# Hbase One-To-Many -Table Load process

Tags: hbase, one-to-many

I have a Hbase customer-order table implementing a  one-to many schema. 
One customer can have multiple orders

So the tables would look something like this add columns to a orders: column family on the Customer table, i.e. orders:1:amount, orders:2:amount

My question is how do I load a atble with such a schema?
I have two files 
cust.txt - has details like cust_id,contact information
order.txt - has details like cust_id, order information

Is it possible to use PIG to load information into Hbase table?
Anyone can point to an example?

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am loading table using Java, but the direction is to use PIG. So I'm looking if someone has tried something similar in PIG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to achieve this in PIG using the TO_MAP function.